# Handle differently encoded records in Oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle, character-encoding

I have to check/join in TABLE_A and TABLE_B where TABLE_A.name like TABle_B.name.
I have the algorithm for the like, but the main problem i cant handle the different encoding.
Because when the tables was done. It was import from different excels, csv-s, java uploads simple oracle insert etc.
And some of them was `&ä&đ&>yc&äđ` encoded so I cant handle `ßruce` =? `Bruce` 
`Ryán` =? `Ryan` etc. but worse.

I found some ASCII functions and others in other topics but i could not manage it.

So if you have some magic tricks for it in oracle sql developer or maybe in java
Thanks.

Comment: Try to correct it on the database level. Maybe do a dump to Unicode, and correct that. I did it once by walking the database for all text columns in java, collecting all non-ASCII, doing an analysis. So after conversion one may verify the results. However that was with less damaged data. Advantage: if you expect repetitions.

Comment: unfortunatly i have only read right in the database

Answer (score 1):

If you can find out what characterset has been used during the import of TABLE_A and TABLE_B, you can convert the values using the `CONVERT` function:

```
UPDATE table_a SET name = CONVERT(name, 'WE8ISO8859P1', 'AL32UTF8');
UPDATE table_b SET name = CONVERT(name, 'WE8MSWIN', 'AL32UTF8');
```

After the conversion, you should be able to join (or check?) both tables without problems.

If you cannot change the data, you could do the conversion on the fly, for instance with:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_a JOIN table_b 
    ON CONVERT(table_a.name, 'WE8ISO8859P1', 'AL32UTF8') =
       CONVERT(table_b.name, 'WE8ISO8859P1', 'AL32UTF8');
```

See the documentation for reference: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions027.htm

Comment: but i have no right to change the structure of the table i can only read.

Comment: ORA-12703: this character set conversion is not supported
12703. 00000 -  "this character set conversion is not supported"
*Cause:    The requested conversion between two character sets in the CONVERT
           function is not implemented
*Action:
I get this error for it :/